# Is it ok to use a service to control UI flow in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a UI flow that has activities launched via intents in separate applications. For example, the first screen would be an activity in application B, launched from my application, the second from application C etc.

To control this flow I was thinking of using a service. Is this the correct approach? Or would it be better to use light weight activities with no UI to launch the external activities?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, but 
I think that [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) may be useful to you.